connection.onLogs from web3.js doesn't send txn after 45 minutes, Why?
I am using connection.onLogs  (from web3.js) to listen to transactions, the issue is after 40-45 minutes, it just stops sending transactions, I need to restart the process to listen to txns again, I have a hacky fix but is there any long term solution for this ?
I tested on Helium and QuickNode's RPC

This might be an issue with websockets getting closed by the server. You may want to use the new web3.js, which provides more customization options for reconnecting: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-started-with-rpc-subscriptions
